# Ionic Cordova web app with Angular 2 and LocalStorage (IndexdB)

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, local-storage

I have a legacy application written in Angular2 and Ionic Cordova, and since last week it no longer works. We made use of IndexdB (LocalStorage) to save user data in, but now on open database call we get 'i.openDatabase is not a function'. Any idea on how to fix this without rewriting the app?

[image]

Trying installing older browser versions, but got the same errors